# Endless "Loading . . . " on user-defined function

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, array-formulas, hashcode, custom-function

I have a formula in a Google Sheets cell that works great, as long as I don't close the spreadsheet.  If I do, when I reopen it later the cells say "Loading ..." for ever.

Here's the formula, in cell H1 :

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(if( A1:A1000 = "", "", strArrayHash(G1:G1000)))
```

I have also tried, and got the same behaviour, with :

```
=if( A1 = "", "", strHash(G1))
=if( A2 = "", "", strHash(G2))
=if( A3 = "", "", strHash(G3))
```

Column A contains a primary key.  If the array formula finds no PK, then it should just write a zero length string.

Cell G1 concatenates columns A through F :

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(if( A1:A1000 = "", "", (A1:A1000 & B1:B1000 & C1:C1000 & D1:D1000 & E1:E1000 & F1:F1000)))
```

My user-defined formula *strArrayHash* is dead simple and very quick when I first use it :

```
function strHash(valCell) {
  var hash = 0;
  if (valCell.length == 0) return hash;
  for (i = 0; i < valCell.length; i++) {
    char = valCell.charCodeAt(i);
    hash = ((hash<<5)-hash)+char;
    hash = hash & hash; // Convert to 32bit integer
  }

  return hash;
}

function strArrayHash(range) {
  var ret = new Array();
  var str = "";
  for (item in range) {
    str = range[item].toString();
    if (str.length > 0) {
      ret[item] = strHash(str);
    } else {
      ret[item] = "";
    }
  };
  return ret;
}
```

The only way I have found to correct the problem is to go in manually and edit the formula in some way.

I thought I had it working by adding a sleep state ...

```
if (str.length > 0) {
  ret[item] = strHash(str);
  Utilities.sleep(10);  // circumvent undocumented execution limit
} else {
```

... but it only works for the user who adds the sleep state.  Shared access users see only "Loading...", even if the last one to edit is seeing the calculated hash values.

Can anyone suggest a reason why this stops working when the spreadsheet is closed?  What can I do about it.

Answer (score 0):

I seem to have solved this.

I realized that it worked happily if I had very few calls from my spreadsheet.  More than two or three and it would start to freak out.

I seem to be back in action as a result of a very simple solution; I added a short sleep into the array handling wrapper ...

```
function strArrayHash(range) {
  var ret = new Array();
  var str = "";
  for (item in range) {
    str = range[item].toString();
    if (str.length > 0) {
      ret[item] = strHash(str);
      Utilities.sleep(10);  // circumvent undocumented execution limit
    } else {
      ret[item] = "";
    }
  };
  return ret;
}
```